# Recursively return an array of positions where i occurs in j

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am not good at Java so I just would like to say in advance "THIS IS MY HOMEWORK" and please "DO NOT DO MY HOMEWORK", this is the very first homework on recursion so this is my first time. Having said that, these are the instructions of my homework but I am not sure the steps that I need to take in order to achieve the goal. All I need is a great guy/girl who can give me good details on how to finish my homework, kind of steps. I have read the book, checked some websites about recursion, but I feel that I need a little more help.

> Write a recursive static method that, given two string s and t,
>   returns an array of all positions where t occurs in s. For example,
>   findLocations("Frances ran and ran", "ran") returns [1, 8, 16].

Comment: That is unfortunately not a good example for a recursive algorithm, it is much more straightforward to use iteration to achieve the result. If it were a linked list that one should return, recursion would be more appropriate, since concatenation of linked lists is fairly natural in contrast to concatenation of arrays.

Comment: +1 for saying you don't want us to do your h/w for you. But we're not a dating website..."all I need is a great guy/girl"...=P At any rate, if any of the answers have helped you with your problem, you should probably click on the tick under that answer (or the answer that has most helped you) in order to mark the answer as accepted/get more rep.

Comment: jajaja that was funny I am not sure if I should flag it as offensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably approach it like this:

1. Given the argumets `inputString` and `substring`, call `index = inputString.indexOf(substring)`.
2. If the `substring` is *not* found (`index` = -1), you should return the empty array (`new int[0]`), since no occurrences of the substring exists in the `inputString`.
3. Otherwise the `substring` *does* exist, in which case you should do the following:

   1. Get the array of indexes for the remaining part of the string, using something like `arr = findLocations(inputString.substring(index+1), substring)`
   2. Adjust the indexes in `arr` by adding `index` to each element.
   3. return `index`, concatenated with `arr`.

Comment: Alright that looks like what I had in mind as help. Thank you Mr.

Answer (score 1):

The way recursion works is that it is usually done with a controlling method, and then an action method. The controlling method holds the recursive call (this is called tail recursion). Using tail recursion to solve this problem would most likely involve a sliding window.  This site has some good information about recursion in Java: http://www.danzig.us/java_class/recursion.html

**Note: Sorry, but in writing out some psuedo I came to producing this code. I really enjoy recursion. I left it in here sloppily so that if you wish to see it perhaps as a check later you can format it**

<strike>public ArrayList findLocations(string target, string window){
     ArrayList locations = new ArrayList();
     return(recurseLocations(target,window,0,locations));
    }

   public ArrayList recurseLocations(string target, string window, int offset, ArrayList locations){
     if(window.length + offset < target.length)return locations;
     bool hit = true;
     for(int i = 0; i < window.length; i++)if(target.charAt(i+offset) != window.charAt(i))hit=false;
     if(hit)locations.add(offset);
     recurseLocations(target,window,(offset + 1),locations);
    }</strike>

Comment: Yes, I already read that website, as I was waiting for any response. Thank you for the link and of course the code that will help me to understand this topic even better for the exam.

Answer (score 1):

As you will be recursing through the first string and actively adding indices, I would recommend using something mutable, such as a List.

As for your recursive method, here are some tips:

```
// Initialize results list first
// Start the search using index = 0 and your empty results list.
ArrayList<Integer> recurSearch(String input, String search, int index, ArrayList<Integer> results)

// Inside recurSearch() 
int index = inputString.indexOf(search string, index);
// Here check the index. If it equals -1, no more matches. Return your result List.
// If does not equal -1, add to result list and return findLocations() using index + 1.
```

I hope this makes sense. As you clearly want to tackle most of this problem yourself, I tried to include as little code as possible. I included my method signature as I hope this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your time and help.